# Sass error Undefined variable

Tags: wallets, error

I just started to set up my first wallet, and I got an an error I cant solve when I run npm start:

`sass error Undefined variable. src/global/style.scss textarea { font-family: $font-family; font-size: 15px;`

I followed the steps in the stellar tutorial on how to set up your first project:  https://developers.stellar.org/docs/building-apps/project-setup/

What could be solution to this? Is the code compiling before the saas variable has been declared?

Im pretty new to coding after just finishing a 3 months bootcamp, but Im eager to learn and build new products!

Thanks for any input :)

Henrik

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the issue. I think it may have something to do with some version mismatch stuff with stencil, autoprefixer and capacitor. I've added some better npm install instructions for ensuring specific versions are installed.

Specifically:

```bash
npm i -D @stencil/postcss @stencil/sass autoprefixer @types/autoprefixer rollup-plugin-node-polyfills
```

You may need to remove your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` files before attempting to reinstall those packages.

```bash
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Hope that helps! You can also pull down the `setup` branch of the repo to see what the currently working version *should* be: https://github.com/stellar/docs-wallet/tree/setup